# Prefix search using lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to do autocomplete using lucene search functionality. I have the following code which searches by the query prefix but along with that it also gives me all the sentences containing that word while I want it to display only sentence or word starting exactly with that prefix.

ex: **m**
--holiday **m**ansion houseboat
--eye **m**uscles
--**m**ovies of all time
--**m**achine

I want it to show only last 2 queries. How to do it am stucked here also I am new to lucene. Please can any one help me in this.  Thanks in advance.

```
       addDoc(IndexWriter w, String title, String isbn) throws IOException {
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new Field("title", title, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

    // use a string field for isbn because we don't want it tokenized
    doc.add(new Field("isbn", isbn, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
    w.addDocument(doc);

 }
```

Main:

```
    try {
        // 0. Specify the analyzer for tokenizing text.
        //    The same analyzer should be used for indexing and searching
        StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();

        // 1. create the index
        Directory index = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexDir));
        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(index, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30), true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED); //3

        for (int i = 0; i < source.size(); i++) {
            addDoc(writer, source.get(i), + (i + 1) + "z");
        }

        writer.close();


        // 2. query
      Term term = new Term("title", querystr);
      //create the term query object
     PrefixQuery query = new PrefixQuery(term);



        // 3. search
        int hitsPerPage = 20;
        IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(index);
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
        TopScoreDocCollector collector =      TopScoreDocCollector.create(hitsPerPage, true);
        searcher.search(query, collector);
        ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;

        // 4. Get results
        for (int i = 0; i < hits.length; ++i) {
            int docId = hits[i].doc;
            Document d = searcher.doc(docId);

            System.out.println(d.get("title"));


        }

        reader.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception (LuceneAlgo.getSimilarString()) : " + e);
    }


}


 }
```

Comment: Check out [Highlighter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/highlighter/index.html).

Comment: Sorry but my question is not about highlighting. I want to make d search to display only starting with that letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your scenario correctly, you want to autocomplete on the title field.

The solution is to have two fields: one analyzed, to enable querying over it, one non-analyzed to have titles indexed without breaking them into individual terms.
Your autocomplete logic should issue prefix queries against the non-analyzed field to match only on the first word. Your term queries should be issued against the analyzed field for matches within the title.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: thanks a lot :) it works.  but now my problem is it takes lot of time to display.

Comment: it also shows repetitive words. how to make it display just 1 word. like i have queries lottery, lottery. it should show only 1 time

Comment: Hi Veena, I'm happy to help. Can you post the new question in a different thread with examples. It will be easier for other people to find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I see two solutions:

1. as suggested by Yahnoosh, save the title field twice, Once as TextField (=analyzed) and once as StringField (not analyzed)
2. save it just as TextField, but When Querying use SpanFirstQuery

> ```
> // 2. query
> Term term = new Term("title", querystr);
> //create the term query object
> PrefixQuery pq = new PrefixQuery(term);
> SpanQuery wrapper = new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper<PrefixQuery>(pq);
> Query final = new SpanFirstQuery(wrapper, 1);
> ```